# Select by double clicking or a single letter a div that makes focus an input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to select text by double clicking or a single letter, how to do it with pure Javascript?

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('text').focus();">test</div>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can you write an example?

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail to your problem

Comment: Yes, try to select a single letter or select all the text "test" with the double click. It is difficult to copy the text because immediately the selection disappears and the input becomes focus. Do you understand now?

Comment: To give an example, I would get the same effect of the facebook chat, if you clicked the chat window the input becomes focus, but if you select text, nothing happens. This is the effect that I would get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so your problem is that you want to `focus` on `text` when you click on `test` but you also want to be able to select the text `test`?

It's easy to cover the first case of selection - just cancel focusing on mouse moving event.

But the second case is more difficult because the `onclick` event comes before `ondblclick` so you can't do much in it.
A possible solution is to delay focusing by a few miliseconds and cancel this operation on doubleclick event

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fyxqe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Okay now I understand. May be this can solve your problem

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dDfRJ/2/

```
$("#click").bind('copy', function() {
  $('input').focus();
});
```

I have bound copy to the text so that when you copy that particular text , the input gets focussed

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want that clicking on the text the input becomes focus, as in my example. My only problem is that it is difficult to copy the text, try selecting the text with a double click or by selecting a single letter. http://jsfiddle.net/eMYh9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you are looking for?

Use the following JS along with html

```
<form name="select_all">
<textarea name="text_area" rows="10" cols="80" 
ondblclick="javascript:this.form.text_area.focus();this.form.text_area.select();">
Selectable text herem selectable text here.
</textarea>
</form>
```

See the DEMO:--- http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/eMYh9/

Comment: But I do not want the text inside the text, the text needs to be out and if I click on the textarea (or input) must become focus, unless you select the text (with a double click or by selecting a single letter), as the facebook chat really!

Comment: it's something hard to understand, please can you draw some wire-frame, so it can be easy to understand and then I can try more appropriately.